# Annotations displayed in scientific notation

Tags: python, heatmap, confusion-matrix

I am converting confusion matrix to heatmap.
The code to convert the dataframe into heatmap is giving numbers in scientific notation on the graph

I dont know what to do because when I display the df everything is fine. And I dont know how to tell seaborn to stop doing something like this

````
```python
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(arr, range(2),range(2))
sns.set(font_scale=1)#for label size
sns.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True,annot_kws={"size": 10},)
```
````

The data frame is like this:
2 rows 2 columns

> 847 .  22
>
> 114 .  17

But in heat map what comes is

> 8.5e+2 .  22
>
> 1.1e+2 .  17

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change the format using the `fmt` parameter, to get integers:

`sns.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True,annot_kws={"size": 10},fmt="d")`

to get float with 1 decimal

`sns.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True,annot_kws={"size": 10},fmt=".1f")`